# What is the correct way to insert bytes at a specific location in a file? C#

Tags: c#

I have one file:
`out.txt`

`out.txt` Contains the line:

> 123456789

We need to write a program so that in a certain position of the file, new numbers can be inserted.
For example: insert the number 2000 in position 3.
The file should have the following result:

> 1232000456789

Program restrictions! Lines cannot be cached from a file. That is, files can weigh up to ~40 GB or even more. Therefore, you need to somehow insert a buffer into the desired position. And move the rest by the length of the inserted character length.

Here is the broken code. It replaces characters. And the rest of the data disappears:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(oldFileForUpdate, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<long, byte[]> keyValuePair in fileStructExtension.Buffer)
    {
        fileStream.Seek(keyValuePair.Key, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        await fileStream.WriteAsync(keyValuePair.Value, 0, keyValuePair.Value.Length, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's just not how files work. If you want to insert something in the middle, you're going to have to re-copy the rest of it. If you want to do that *quickly* with large files, then memory-mapped files may be the way to go, but: there's no magic tricks here AFAIK. To be honest, though: a file format that has padding might be a better option (so you can usually just update an existing oversized page, without copying everything later in the file)

Comment: Database engines are basically file management engines optimized to do precisely this. Instead of working with a monolithic files you are working with records.

Comment: Databases don't work for me. This is the structure of the game file. I analyze it and insert it into the old update files in certain positions. The analysis is working. But the insert ... Not really. It replaces memory. But does not add to a specific position.

Comment: As it has been said - if every change needs to be persistent, you gonna need to rewrite the whole file every time. No other way.

Comment: At least help or tell me how to correctly shift the remainder before writing the buffer? That is, after 123 and the insertion of 2000, shift further by 4 characters?

Comment: it's just so obvious that the bytes are fixed in a single position on the disk and won't move automatically. How can a memory cell in flash or a magnetic element knows that it has to copy the state from some far away element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to copy data to a temp file like so:

1. Copy all the bytes before the insertion point to the temp file.
2. Copy the bytes to be inserted to the temp file.
3. Copy the remainder of the bytes from the original file to the temp file.
4. Delete the original file.
5. Rename the temp file to the original file.

Sample implementation (adjust the buffer size to taste):

```
public static void Insert(string filename, long offset, byte[] data)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];

    var tempFile = filename + ".tmp";

    using (var input = File.OpenRead(filename))
    using (var output = File.OpenWrite(tempFile))
    {
        while (offset > 0)
        {
            int n = (int)Math.Min(offset, buffer.Length);
            n = input.Read(buffer, 0, n);

            if (n <= 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Input file is too short.");

            output.Write(buffer, 0, n);
            offset -= n;
        }

        output.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        input.CopyTo(output);
    }

    File.Delete(filename);
    File.Move(tempFile, filename);
}
```

This does of course require that you can create a temporary file in the same folder as the source folder, and that there is enough free disk space for the temporary file plus the original file.

Comment: You should specify `offset` as a `long` if you want to write at offsets above 4 GB. Also, you should definitely _not_ ignore the return value of `Read`. `Read` might return less than you asked (it probably won't with `FileStream` unless you reach the end of the stream, but it's a bad idea to rely on undocumented implementation details).

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Good point about using long, but in terms of the return value: The full amount will be read if that number of bytes are available, and we already checked that there will be that many bytes available when checking `input.Length < offset`. Of course, the available bytes could change if some other thread/process changes the file length - if that happens the only safe thing would be to throw an exception.  I'll change the code above to throw in that event.

Comment: That's an observation based on the current implementation. The documentation only states "This might be less than the number of bytes requested _if that number of bytes are not currently available_" (emphasis mine), with no clear definition of what "currently available" means. It's not like using the return value makes for much more complicated code anyway: just use it instead of `n`.

Comment: I don't believe it's just an observation: I believe that `Stream.Length` does indeed indicate the number of bytes available. But you miss the point about throwing if the length of the file changes: Clearly something is far wrong if that happens (i.e. if some other thread/process has modified the file), so it's better to throw an exception. Of course it's likely that an exception would have been thrown due to an I/O sharing error so this code wouldn't even execute - but it's safer to throw just in case.

Comment: However it does simplify the code to just check for a return value of 0 from the `Read()`. If that happens you have to avoid an infinite loop by either throwing an exception  or break out of the loop and carry on writing the rest of the data. Obviously the only correct solution there is to throw an exception, so I've modified the code to do so. This also means that you don't need to check the length before starting the copy, since it will throw inside the loop if the file length is less than the specified offset.